# Using QWebFrame.setContent() with unicode (Python+PySide)

Tags: python, pyside, qwebpage

I'm using QWebKit to render a a pdf-page. Untill now, I used `setHtml()`, to feed the html code to the QMainFrame and then `render()` to print the content or export it to pdf. So far so good, but I want to use `setContent()` to include inline-svg-images to the frame, which get not displayed, using `setHtml()`.

But `setContent()` only accepts QByteArray, and the html-Code is in unicode. How do I feed the unicode string to `setContent()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get a byte array out of a `unicode` is to encode it.